# npm install webpack --save-dev error

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I download a demo "react-redux-demo",and when I use the commond "npm install webpack --save-dev" to install webpack, the error shows.

This is the log

```
8351 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-51622fc2de18aa59.lock for D:\work\test\react-redux-demo\node_modules\.staging 
8352 warn The package history is included as both a dev and production dependency.
 8353 warn The package react is included as both a dev and production dependency. 
8354 warn The package react-router-config is included as both a dev and production dependency.
 8355 warn The package react-router-native is included as both a dev and production dependency. 
8356 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\work\test\react-redux-demo\node_modules\.staging\loader-utils-21a7d1c0\node_modules\big.js'
        -> 'D:\work\test\react-redux-demo\node_modules\.staging\big.js-134af3f2' 
8357 verbose cwd D:\work\test\react-redux-demo 
8358 verbose Windows_NT
    10.0.14393
 8359 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "webpack" "--save-dev" 
8360 verbose node v8.4.0 
8361 verbose npm  v5.3.0
 8362 error path D:\work\test\react-redux-demo\node_modules\.staging\loader-utils-21a7d1c0\node_modules\big.js 
8363 error code ENOENT
 8364 error errno -4058
 8365 error syscall rename 
8366 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\work\test\react-redux-demo\node_modules\.staging\loader-utils-21a7d1c0\node_modules\big.js'
        -> 'D:\work\test\react-redux-demo\node_modules\.staging\big.js-134af3f2' 
8367 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
 8368 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Comment: try to run `npm cache clean` first, then run `npm i` again.

Comment: Thanks,but still doesn't work,I don't know Why,guess my project is a little differen